# ¿Qué está mal con estas reglas de descuento con PHP en Wordpress (Woocommerce)?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

estoy intentando comprender qué problema tiene este código:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'aplicar_descuentos_cuotas', 10, 1 );

function aplicar_descuentos_cuotas( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    $cuotas_count = 0;
    $subtotal_cuotas = 0;
    $efectivo_selected = false;

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

        if ( has_term( 'Cuotas', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            $cuotas_count += $cart_item['quantity'];
            $subtotal_cuotas += $cart_item['line_subtotal'];
        }
    }

    if ( $cuotas_count == 1 && WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method') == 'cod' ) {
        $descuento = $subtotal_cuotas * 0.05;
        $cart->add_fee( __('Descuento por pago en efectivo (5%)', 'woocommerce'), -$descuento );
    }

    if ( $cuotas_count > 1 ) {
        $descuento = $subtotal_cuotas * 0.20;
        $cart->add_fee( __('Descuento por el pago de más de un curso (20%)', 'woocommerce'), -$descuento );
    }
}
```

tengo un sitio que utiliza woocommerce y necesito hacer dos descuentos distintos, no dependientes entre sí:

1. Si el usuario se lleva en el carrito dos o más productos de la categoría "cuotas", se le debería hacer un 20% de descuento.
2. Si el usuario utiliza el medio de pago "cod" (=efectivo), se le debe hacer un 5% de descuento.

Por algún motivo, el sitio hace uno solo de los dos descuentos, no ambos juntos.